# Динамический массив внутри компонента

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hook, react-hook-form

Всем привет!
Есть задачка, реализовать компонент для создания новой статьи в блоге.
В самой блоке редактирования есть поле тег.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После нажатия на Add Tag, ниже должен появится такой же input и кнопка.
На сервер теги отправляются массивом. Мой подход следующий, есть стейт:
`const [tags, setTags] = useState(['']);` который я хочу заполнять значениями(tag).
Далее идет ф-ия:

```
const createTags = () => {
    return tags.map((tag, i) => (
      <div className={style.tag} key={i}>
        <label className={style.label}>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Tag"
            className={style.tagInput}
            {...register(`tagList.${i}`)}
          />
          {tags.length > 1 ? (
            <button type="button" className={style.btnDelete} onClick={() => deleteTag()}>
              Delete
            </button>
          ) : null}
          <button type="button" className={style.btnAdd} onClick={(e) => addTag(e, i)}>
            Add tag
          </button>
        </label>
      </div>
    ));
  };
```

Из-за того, что по дефолту в массиве есть элемент, то индекс тегов смещается и первым эл-ом является пустая строка. Если в состоянии убрать строку, то в моем случае поле инпут и button не появится.
Возможно нужно изменить подход, но этот же компонент я бы хотел использовать при редактировании статьи, т.е. что бы в инпутах лежали данные из сервера, в случае если я редактирую.
Буду рад помощи!

Comment: `После нажатия на Add Tag, ниже должен появится такой же input и кнопка.` как-то странно ты собрался реализовывать работу с тегами... Куча инпутов с кнопкой "Add".

Comment: В коде пока этого нет, но button будет только у последнего(пустого инпута). А ты как бы сделал?

Comment: См.мой ответ...

Answer (score 0):

Обычно с тегами делают нечто такое... Стилей в примере нет, но думаю что идея будет понятна.

Теги добавляются в список. Из списка теги можно удалять, нажимая на крестик...

```js
//
function App() {
  const [tag, setTag] = React.useState([])
  return <section>
    <Add add={setTag} />
    <List tag={tag} act={setTag} />
    <div>
      <button>Send</button>
    </div>
  </section>
}
//
function List({tag, act}) {
  return <ul>
    {tag.map(o => <Item key={o.id} data={o} act={act} />)}
  </ul>
}
//
function Item({data, act}) {
  const del = _ => act(a => a.filter(o => o.id != data.id))
  return <li>
    {data.val}
    <span onClick={del}> x</span>
  </li>
}
//
function Add({add}) {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState([])
  const act = _ => add(a => {
    const o = {
      id: new Date(),
      val
    }
    setVal('')
    return [...a, o]
  })
  return <div>
    <input value={val} onChange={e => setVal(e.target.value)} />
    <button onClick={act}>Add</button>
  </div>
}
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#like_button_container');
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(domContainer);
root.render(<App />);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
<div id="like_button_container"></div>
```